# How to audit print jobs on windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing, reporting

I've set our 2003 Server to log spooler information events, which are then recorded in the system log (Event 10) in Event Viewer. This records the user who sent the print job, along with date/time, file name, and # of pages. What I would like to do, is be able to run a monthly report with stats including the aforementioned properties. Is there a way to enable this in Windows Server, or would I need 3rd party software?

Comment: We use [PaperCut Print Logger](http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/print_logger/) (it's free) as it not only provides raw logs, but generates HTML for daily, monthly and all-time logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to buy anything as PowerShell should be able to easily handle the task you're looking to produce. This [PowerShell / VB Script Discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/007be664-1d8d-461c-9e0b-d8177106d4f8) is along the lines of what you're looking to accomplish, however you'll need to tweak it to suit your needs. Once you've written your script use the Windows Scheduler to schedule the job to run once a month and Bobs your Uncle.